# Problem with upgrading php version from 7.4 to 8

Tags: php-8

I am using Joomla version 3.10 and after upgrading the php version from 7.4 to 8.0, I received this error.

`Fatal error: Unparenthesized` a ? b : c ? d : e`is not supported. Use either`(a ? b : c) ? d : e`or`a ? b : (c ? d : e) `in /home/public_html/language/fa-IR/fa-IR.localise.php on line 115`

**I put the source code of fa-IR.localise.php on line 115 below:**

```
`if (strpos($return, self::MONTH_LENGTH) !== false) {
            $return = str_replace(self::MONTH_LENGTH, $m < 7 ? 31 : $m < 12 ? 30 : self::leap_persian($y) ? 30 : 29 , $return);`
```

Thank you for helping me.

When I go back to php version 7.4, the problem is solved

Comment: That’s a bug to report to joomla (if it hasn’t already been reported) probably. What is unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$return = str_replace(self::MONTH_LENGTH, ($m < 7 ? 31 : ($m < 12 ? 30 : (self::leap_persian($y) ? 30 : 29) ) ) , $return);
```

Operations need after PHP 7.4 this **(** ... **)** brace's.